# How to C3850 activate license to ipservices

Tags: cisco, switch, bgp, license

We have Cisco C3850 running `ipbase` license recently we decided to run `BGP` protocol for that we need `ipservices` license.

Question: Do i need to buy new license or i have already that i just need to activate using `right-to-use`?

```
C3850#show switch
Switch/Stack Mac Address : 6c99.8962.2801 - Local Mac Address
Mac persistency wait time: Indefinite
                                             H/W   Current
Switch#   Role    Mac Address     Priority Version  State
------------------------------------------------------------
*1       Active   6c99.8962.2801     15     M0      Ready
 2       Standby  c414.3c9b.4190     1      M0      Ready
```

License:

```
C3850#show license right-to-use
 Slot#  License name   Type     Count   Period left
----------------------------------------------------------
 1      ipbase       permanent     N/A   Lifetime

License Level on Reboot: ipbase


 Slot#  License name   Type     Count   Period left
----------------------------------------------------------
 2      ipbase       permanent     N/A   Lifetime

License Level on Reboot: ipbase
```

Summary:

```
C3850#show license right-to-use usage
 Slot#  License Name     Type     usage-duration(y:m:d)  In-Use  EULA
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
 1      ipservices     permanent    0 :0 :0                no    no
 1      ipservices     evaluation   0 :0 :0                no    no
 1      ipbase         permanent    2 :0 :14               yes   yes
 1      ipbase         evaluation   0 :0 :0                no    no
 1      lanbase        permanent    0 :0 :0                no    no
 1      apcount        evaluation   0 :0 :0                no    no
 1      apcount        base         0 :0 :0                no    no
 1      apcount        adder        0 :0 :0                no    no

 Slot#  License Name     Type     usage-duration(y:m:d)  In-Use  EULA
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
 2      ipservices     permanent    0 :0 :0                no    no
 2      ipservices     evaluation   0 :0 :0                no    no
 2      ipbase         permanent    2 :0 :14               yes   yes
 2      ipbase         evaluation   0 :0 :0                no    no
 2      lanbase        permanent    0 :0 :0                no    no
 2      apcount        evaluation   0 :0 :0                no    no
 2      apcount        base         0 :0 :0                no    no
 2      apcount        adder        0 :0 :0                no    no
```

Can't i just activate using following command?

```
C3850#license right-to-use activate ?
  apcount     configure the AP-count licenses on the switch
  ipbase      activate ipbase license on the switch
  ipservices  activate Ipservices license on the switch
  lanbase     activate lanbase license on the switch
```

## Update:

In following command its showing this, Does that means i already have license and i just need to Activate it? Look at `Index 1` what that means?

```
C3850#show license right-to-use detail
Index 1:  License Name: ipservices
           Period left: Lifetime
           License Type: permanent
           License State: Not Activated
           License Count: Non-Counted
           License Location: Slot 1
Index 2:  License Name: ipservices
           Period left: 90
           License Type: evaluation
           License State: Not Activated
           License Count: Non-Counted
           License Location: Slot 1
Index 3:  License Name: ipbase
           Period left: Lifetime
           License Type: permanent
           License State: Active, In use
           License Count: Non-Counted
           License Location: Slot 1
Index 4:  License Name: ipbase
           Period left: 90
           License Type: evaluation
           License State: Not Activated
           License Count: Non-Counted
           License Location: Slot 1
Index 5:  License Name: lanbase
           Period left: Lifetime
           License Type: permanent
           License State: Not Activated
           License Count: Non-Counted
           License Location: Slot 1
```

Comment: If the answer answered your question, you should accept it. It keeps popping up, looking for an answer.

Comment: I am facing the same scenario. Did it worked?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> From [This Cisco Config Guide](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst3850/software/release/3se/system_management/configuration_guide/b_sm_3se_3850_cg/b_sm_3se_3850_cg_chapter_0100.html):

```
Permanent licenses—Purchased with a specific feature set with no expiration date.
Evaluation licenses—Pre-installed on the switch and is valid for only a 90 day in-use period.
```

You can run `license right-to-use activate ip-services all accepteula` to activate ipservices, and then restart the switch.

In general if you activate an image you don't have a license for it will warn you that you must purchase or deactivate in 90 days, etc.

Comment: This is production switch so i have to think about before i run that commands. Couple years ago we purchased that switch and nobody knows what feature we purchased.. what other option i have to find out?

Comment: You can contact Cisco if you have a valid service agreement, but the Cisco document I linked to explains the license types and how to install them. Just fyi, even at the end of the evaluation period the services you installed will continue to work, however you would be violating the EULA by not uninstalling the eval licenses.

Comment: But in Index 1 it is show permanent and lifetime. Does that means I already have license purchased and now just need to activate?

Comment: @Satish Yes, thats correct.